# SQL Server - How to get IP of your own server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I saw that it is possible to connect to remote SQL servers by using their IP inside Manangement studio. Now I want to allow the database on my computer to be accessible remotely.
How do I find out the IP of my own SQL server so that I can use that IP to login remotely ?

Comment: if you use a windows server: type ipconfig (on the server). there you can find your ip adress (not the 192.169..). this ip adress is also you sql server ip adress

Comment: I don't mean to be snobby, but if you do not know how to find your own IP, you may want to consider learning a little more about network basics before even venturing into a security-sensitive application like this one. 

If you're an auditory learner like myself, I can recommend the earlier episodes of [Security Now](http://www.grc.com/sn/past/2006.htm) which cover lots of networking and internet security basics (besides lots of other interesting topics). Episodes 25 and 26 were particularly good.

Comment: one of the suggested queries was - SELECT client_net_address
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
WHERE Session_id = @@SPID;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT 
      client_net_address = CASE WHEN client_net_address = '<local machine>' 
                                THEN '127.0.0.1' 
                                ELSE client_net_address 
                           END  
    , local_net_address = ISNULL(local_net_address, '127.0.0.1')
    , server_name = @@SERVERNAME
    , machine_name = SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
WHERE session_id = @@SPID;
```

Comment: 1st query gives me a column called - client_net_address. It is an IP address which is different from my internet IP address (google "what is my ip"). So, is it enough to type the client_net_address in a remote computer's management studio and login to my computer's database ?

Comment: No. In order to reach your computer (which is behind your router, I assume) from the Internet, you'd have to set up so-called port forwarding. Depending on your router make and model, there are bound to be lots of good manuals/walkthroughs online. Before you go there though, make sure you know a little about the security implications of doing so.

Comment: But if by "remote" you mean a different computer within your own network, then, yes. It will only work if your SQL Server is set up to allow connections over the TCP/IP protocol however, which many versions aren't by default upon first installation.

Comment: @Mels - Security implications...okay what keywords do I enter in google to get some good articles about that ?

Comment: @Mels - actually, i also want remote computers outside "my network/lan???" to be able to access my database.

Comment: Check out the comment I left on the Q itself, I linked to a great podcast. Keyphrases like "network security basics", "port forwarding security" and the like should get you going. Be prepared to either learn a lot about the subject or take some pretty great risks though.

Comment: Also, you might be better off asking this question (mentioning that you need access from outside your private network) over on ServerFault. It's full of sysadmins that generally know more about network security than programmers will admit ;-)

Comment: @Devart - got 3 rows, 2 of which are repeats and one has the 127. thing. BTW, what is your query doing ?

Comment: @Devart - thanks. what is that IP number returned by the query and can you tell me how your query works ?

Comment: This query returns the IP address of the server (client_net_address), your IP address (local_net_address), the name of the server instance (server_name), and the name of the PC where the server is installed (machine_name).

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME;
```

Comment: Thanks. That taught me something new, but did not answer my question.

Comment: Actually on your sql server,you just need to enable remote connection and using the @@SERVERNAME you can connect to your server from other location

Answer (score 1):

You can Ping your computer name. do not ping "localhost" as that will give you 127.0.0.1. You can go "ping my-pc" and it will resolve your IP address through your DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

Visit this address to get your public IP address as Google sees it.

https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+ip

Note: You may need to open up ports on your router and open up ports in your firewall to connect remotely. Additionally, your SQL server may be bound to only on your localhost 127.0.0.1 address. You may need to look up the instructions to accept connections on all of your IP addresses for your server.

Comment: @Brent-  A friendly suggestion - Please delete your answer, ppl tend to downvote in such situations.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @IPAdress NVARCHAR(50)=''
SELECT @IPAdress = CASE WHEN dec.client_net_address = '<local machine>'
    THEN (SELECT TOP(1) c.local_net_address FROM
        sys.dm_exec_connections AS c WHERE c.local_net_address IS NOT NULL)
    ELSE dec.client_net_address
    END FROM sys.dm_exec_connections AS dec WHERE dec.session_id = @@SPID;
SELECT @IPAdress
```

Comment: Please add a short explanation.

Comment: You really shouldn't post only code to an answer, please explain your answer.

Comment: This will give you the Client IP Address, if client_net_address = '<local machine>' and local_net_address is null for the session.